# Jenkinsfile not found Does not meet criteria

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins (Jenkins ver. 2.60.1) multi branch pipeline job with Git SCM. In the root of the repository on **master** branch I have a valid **Jenkinsfile** but when I scan the job I get:

```
  Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
    Does not meet criteria
```

Job config:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the question with job config?

Comment: It seems, it has no file called `Jenkinsfile` on the top level.

Comment: I have verified that there is a Jenkinsfile in the root of the repo on all branches. I have added most of the job config - remaining are just using default values.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having same issue Jenkins not finding Jenkinsfile that is definitely present

Answer (score 11):

You might look at this Jenkins issue and see if it helps.
[Jenkinsfile not found in PR on GitHub](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54126?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)

We were having a similar problem and the workaround listed in that issue at least got us past the problem. In our case the problem stems from using Github's "Allow rebase merging" option when merging pull requests, and then continuing to add commits into that same branch. Then on the next PR we would see this problem.

The workaround is to delete the contents of:
$jenkins_home/org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMProbe.cache

and then have Jenkins rescan the repository.

Another option is to create a clean branch, cherry-pick the commits from the branch that Jenkins claims has no Jenkinfile, and then create another PR from your new branch.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Removing the cache work. [This bug has been fixed](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54126?focusedCommentId=384240&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-384240) in the current version of `github-branch-source` and `github` plugin

Comment: Removing the cache worked for me too. Thanks!